# Dynamic markup in Wicket

Tags: wicket

Is it possible to generate the markup for a `MarkupContainer` dynamically, i.e. without storing an HTML file for it?

I thought about reading the markup as a plain string from the database to offer CMS-like functionality.

Comment: Great! I'm going to use this with JTexy lightweight markup language (http://code.google.com/p/jtexy/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question and I'm not sure if it is possible, but my guess would be to start off looking at the [IMarkupLoader](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/loader/IMarkupLoader.html) and [IMarkupResourceStreamProvider](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/IMarkupResourceStreamProvider.html) interfaces and implementing classes and see how far you get from there.
I'd be interested in anything you find / implement that actually gets this done!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That did it! The MarkupContainer has to implement `IMarkupResourceStreamProvider` and its method `getMarkupResourceStream()`. Also, you create a class that derives (for example) from `AbstractResourceStream`. There, you can implement a method that just returns an `InputStream`. `getMarkupResourceStream()` then just returns an instance of this new class.
The javadoc says this was even transparent to caching.

Comment: This is well documented in the reference guide under [17.5 Generating HTML markup from code](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/advanced.html#advanced_5).

Answer (score -1):

Another (simpler) way to do it would be to use a label with disabled markup escaping :

```
Label<String> label = new Label<String>("id", "<a href='....'><span>foo<em>bar</em></span></a>");
label.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
add(label);
```

Be careful though, as this might lead to security breaches (**HTML/JS injection**).

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I'm not sure if it's what I was looking for, though. I want to use the dynamic markup to be used by a MarkupContainer, i.e. I expect certain wicket:ids in the markup and I want to add further components to the container which should then be mapped to those ids. I'm afraid that's not possible with your solution.

Comment: This is a really bad idea, considering the security breaches, but also the abuse of a Label to display plain HTML.